# Swift SubView In front of tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Im trying to display a custom activity loader.

```
let activityLoader = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect.zero, type: NVActivityIndicatorType.ballPulse, color: .red, padding: 50)
activityLoader.center = self.view.center

view.addSubview(activityLoader)
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.activityLoader())
activityLoader.startAnimating()
```

Works on ViewControllers with no tableView.

When I have a table view it does not work.

How can i display the activity loader to the front of my ViewController with a tableView?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're bringing another activity to front other than the one you created in this line

```
  let activityLoader = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect.zero, type: NVActivityIndicatorType.ballPulse, color: .red, padding: 50)
```

///

here you bring another one from a function call

```
 self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.activityLoader())
```

change to this

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.activityLoader)
```

Comment: Also, you need to remove `func activityLoader()` and make it a property `var activityLoader: NVActivityIndicatorView?` instead.

Comment: Right , the actual one is not getting to front